# Prove that the linear equation (3) has a unique solution.

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

Let 6 : RM + H, where H is a Hilbert space, be the feature map. Let K : R" x R" + R be the corresponding kernel function, i.e., K(x, y) = ($(x), 6(y)) for all x, y ER". We used the following linear equations in the proof of representer theorem: N (a-Şco(2), 6(*;)) = 0, j= 1,...,N, - Cio(Xi), o (CA) = 0, j = 1,...,N, i=1 where C1, ...,CN are the unknowns, a is a given vector in H, and X1,..., IN are given vectors in R”. Assume the kernel function K symmetric positive definite, i.e., for any natural number m and distinct vectors 21, 22, ..., Zm ER”, the matrix K = (K(zi, z;)]mal ERmxm is symmetric positive definite. Prove that the linear equation (3) has a unique solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line ($j=1,\ldots,N$) has the form
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N\langle\phi(x_i),\phi(x_j)\rangle c_i = \langle\mathbf{a},\phi(x_j)\rangle .
$$
Let $K = [K(x_i,x_j)]_{i,j=1}^N$ and $b = [\langle\mathbf a,\phi(x_j)\rangle]_{j=1}^N$. Since $\langle\phi(x_i),\phi(x_j)\rangle = K(x_i,x_j)$, the linear system can be written as $Kc = b$. And as $K$ is positive definite, it is invertible. So, the system has the unique solution $c = K^{-1}b$.